# .on() doesnt works on dynamic elements?

Tags: jquery

My [code](http://jsfiddle.net/qcdzS/1/) :

## HTML

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="mappa-infobox">
        <div class="pulsanti">
            <span class="pulsante selected">YES</span>
            <span class="pulsante">NO</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="example"></div>
```

## jQuery

```
$(".mappa-infobox .pulsante").on("click", function () {
    console.log("ciao");
});

$(window).load(function () {
    $('#example').html($('#box').html());
});
```

seems that, after the document is loaded and the `mappa-infobox` "cloned" inside the `example` div, the handlers are not fired. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `on()` in delegated-event manner:

```
$("#example").on("click", ".pulsante", function () {
    console.log("ciao");
});
```

Where `#example` works as a parent element of `.pulsante`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/arEWv/

Comment: so I always need to specify the parent? I can't, parent could be "dynamic" also...

Comment: If so, then use $(document) instead of the parent ID/class, i.e. $(document).on("click", ".pulsante", function () {

Comment: @markzzz You may use either `$(document)` (as *thedixon* noted), or `$("body")`.

Comment: Uhm no...it doesn't works! Also #example is generated dynamically, can't get the handler...

Comment: @markzzz Just try the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/arEWv/1/. It *should* work by all means.

Comment: I believe, but in fact on my code it doesnt works! I try to put the same scenario... but don't know how to do it...

Comment: the problem is different : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033506/why-i-cant-attach-an-dynamic-event-handler-to-this-element