# Why I can't attach an dynamic event handler to this element?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

My [code](http://jsfiddle.net/arEWv/7/) :

## HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:500px"></div>

<div id="mappa-infowindow" style="display:none;">
    <div style="background-color:#ffffff;">            
        <span style="cursor:pointer;" class="pulsanteProva">Click</span>
    </div>            
</div>
```

## jQuery/Maps

```
$("body").on("click", ".pulsanteProva", function () {
    alert("clicked");
});

$(window).load(function () {
    var templateFinestra = $('#mappa-infowindow');
    var infoWindowOptions = {
        content: templateFinestra.html(),
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-87, -88)
    };
    var infowindow = new InfoBox(infoWindowOptions);    

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.745334,12.738430);
    var options = { zoom: 12, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, map: map, title: 'Example' });   
    
    markerClick = function () {
        infowindow.setContent(templateFinestra.html());
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    };    
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerClick);
});
```

when I click on the marker, than on the span `Click`, it must show to me the alert, but in fact it doesnt works. Seems that the handler is not attached? Why?

Neither putting the `on` inside the function and attach it from the map parent works http://jsfiddle.net/arEWv/9/

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to be ready before attaching an event to the body?

Comment: It works fine in your fiddle for me

Comment: @wirey : I mean the "click" showed after clicking on the Google Map Marker. Check the new link, it was visible in the bottom :)

Comment: @KevinB : I'm using "on", so I don't care about... in fact for the "future" new dynamic elements it should works, but in fact it doesnt!

Comment: @markzzz right, but the body node must still exist for your code to work, if your code is in the <head>, the body doesn't exist yet.

Comment: but my code is in the body... `no wrap (body)`

Comment: markzzz http://jsfiddle.net/arEWv/11/

Comment: well @azizpunjani, this seems to works, but why? In fact, it is not a real "dynamic" handler, because I create a handler every time I manage the infowindow...

Comment: @azizpunjani : also, the problem is that if I have more infowindow, when I click on One, the handler is invoked on all infowindow! Damn...

Comment: It seems to be a combination of things. Google maps stops event propagations from the infobox and hence they don't propagate all the way up the document. If the event is added after the infobox element has been added to the dom it works. I'm not sure there's a dynamic way to listen for those events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like google map remove all events attached to embedded elements before rendering.

See that working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arEWv/8/)

```
markerClick = function () {
        infowindow.setContent(templateFinestra.html());
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        setTimeout(function(){$('.pulsanteProva').click(function(){alert('clicked');});},500);
    };
```

And this one not working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arEWv/12/)

```
markerClick = function () {
        infowindow.setContent(templateFinestra.html());
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
       $('.pulsanteProva').click(function(){alert('clicked');});
};
```

Comment: Well, so how can I manage a dynamic event handler in this way? I think I need to create it every time...

Comment: Found a way! Using `google.maps.event.addListener` of google!