# Why I can't call that function from inside 2 functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/P87q3/) is my code:

```
inserisciMarker();

function scorriAllaLista(param) {
    alert(param);
}

function inserisciMarker() {
    markerClick = function () {
        $('#example').attr("onclick", "scorriAllaLista('hello'); return false;");
    };

    markerClick();
}
```

clicking on link, `Uncaught ReferenceError: scorriAllaLista is not defined`

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Most likely it isn't defined globally. `window.scorriAllaLista = scorriAllaLista` Why are you setting an onclick attribute with javascript rather than binding an event?

Comment: You should not use `attr()` to add event handlers!

Comment: @both: I can't, for this unresolved problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033506/why-i-cant-attach-an-dynamic-event-handler-to-this-element

Comment: seems that google maps "remove" all handlers.. so I can't attach it!

Comment: It doesn't remove handlers, you're just miss-interpreting results. Events simply aren't bubbling because google maps stops them before they reach the body. (which was explained in your previous question) **Bind the event using the google maps api**. That's why they included that functionality after all.

Comment: @KevinB: can you give a small example?

Comment: @markzzz If i did it would be from a google result, I'm pretty sure that's been done many times before.

Comment: if I wrote `google.maps.event.addListener($('#example'), 'click', alert("ciao"));` is not invoked clickin on the href!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you realy must do it the way you do, you can add the method to the global `window` object, similar to this:

```
window.scorriAllaLista = function(param) {
    alert(param);
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UUHNS/) - add method to `window`

---

As you are already using `return false` you might get away with a `href="#"` as `return false;` already stops propagation as well as prevents default behaviour.

Comment: +1 because this solves OP's real problem (which is somewhat different from what was initially told). I tested a simple variation using a dynamic function (thus avoiding the param).

Comment: But why I need to add function to the dom? the function should be visible inside functions.

Comment: @markzzz: I'm not 100% sure but it definetly has to do with the fact the method is called from within an `onclick` attribute. I don't know the intrinsics but the error message you got indicated the execution expected `scorriAllaLista` to be accessable on a global level. As [**dystroy**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/dystroy)' answer shows, using `.click()` will work without adding your method to `window` but you are not able to do that as you stated in your comments.

Answer (score 10):

That's not how you bind event handler using jQuery.

Replace

```
$('#example').attr("onclick", "scorriAllaLista('hello'); return false;");
```

with

```
$('#example').click(function(){
    scorriAllaLista('hello');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Correct answer, probably the simplest solution, !!/ninjad again :)

Comment: The `return false` is redundant in this case.

Comment: @AndreasGrech I don't see why. Returning false tells jQuery to both stop propagation of the event and to prevent default click behavior. Depending on OP's will, it may be useful.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: OP used `return false` in original code so the comment might be better on the original question directed at OP?

Comment: @markzzz your question isn't clear ? Are you trying to inject code in an iframe coming from another origin ?

Comment: No! I'm in a scenario (unresolved) like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033506/why-i-cant-attach-an-dynamic-event-handler-to-this-element

Comment: I can't attach handlers because google api will remove all handlers.

Comment: Yea good point, I actually had forgotten about halting propagation.

Comment: @markzzz For your real problem (which isn't the one I answered), you should be able to use François's solution.

Comment: +1 as this is correct and this is how the event should be bound even though OP is not able to use this approach. Very useful answer though for future users who are able to use this option.